# Capture onTap on Webview and send the details

Tags: android, ios, flutter, android-studio

Is there any to get the click event from webView or how i can get the current url if he url changed. or when the url changed need to reload the webview.

Note: Not in Button click action

```
 Stack(
            children: [
    
    
              WebView(
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                initialUrl: mainUrl,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController){
                  _controller.complete(webViewController);
                },
                onPageFinished: (url){
                  allJsfile();
    
                },
                
              ),
              GestureDetector(
    
                onTapDown: (_) => print('webview onTapDown $_'),
                onTapUp: (_) => print('webview onTapUp $_'),
                onTap: () => print('webview onTap'),
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Hi! You want to get current url inside `onTap` handler of GestureDetector, right?

Comment: yes. I want to get url if user click on webview navigate to other page then i want the url

Answer (score 2):

You can get this by this way.
just use "navigationDelegate" method inside Webview.

```
              WebView(
                  initialUrl: provider.webUrl,
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  navigationDelegate: (action) {
                    if (action.url ==
                        "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f") {
                      return NavigationDecision.prevent;
                    } else {
                      return NavigationDecision.navigate;
                    }
                  },
                  debuggingEnabled: true,
                  gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
                )
```

If you want to Navigate all kind of pages then use

```
navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest action) {
   return NavigationDecision.navigate;
}
```

and you can get navigated url

```
navigationDelegate: (action) {
  print(action.url);
}
```